# Получить Title из AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-textview, android-dialog

Есть AlertDialog

```
final AlertDialog.Builder ratingdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ratingdialog.setTitle("My title")
```

Пробую так получить `Title`, но `dialogTitle == null`

```
AlertDialog d = ratingdialog.create();
int textViewId = getResources().getIdentifier( "alertTitle", "id", "android" );
TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) d.findViewById(textViewId);
dialogTitle.setTextColor(Color.RED);
d.show();
```

Как мне получить этот Title?

Answer (score 1):

Ну да вы нашли текстовое поле, а какое значение вы ему присвоили? Вот там и получается null. Может лучше самостоятельно присваивать значение в title?

```
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.somelayout, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    b.setView(promptsView);
    TextView tv = (TextView)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.fp_name);
    tv.setTextColor(R.color.WHITE);
    b.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    b.setPositiveButton("ДА", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //do positive things
        }
    });
    AlertDialog a=b.create();
    a.show();
```

Обновлено. Создайте somelayout и добавьте в него нужное вам поле с нужным цветом.

Comment: Суть в том, что у меня титл написан белым цветом, и мне нужно программно поменять его цвет. А чтобы это сделать, мне надо сначала получить его в переменную. Самому Title я присвоил значение через `setTitle()`

Comment: @MrKlonwar,внес изменения в ответ.

Comment: Но setView же устанавливает контент самого диалога, а не его Title

Comment: Решение - подключить promptsView через setCustomView. `b.setCustomView(promptsView);` Если напишите, то отмечу верным

Comment: Я вам предложил "раздуть" разметку для диалога. А создать разметку вам нужно самостоятельно или в этом тоже есть трудность? В раздутой разметке найти поле, сделать его титл и выставить для него нужный цвет. Убрал лишнюю строчку из ответа, так сделать нельзя "b.setTitle("Super Title?");"

Comment: А, все, я понял. Хорошо, спасибо. Можно и так

Comment: Не проще создать свой стиль и сделать цвет тайтла другим цветом?